# Sorting an array of hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have one array of hashes as following:

```
[{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
```

I want to sort this array of hashes based on the **value** of key `"k2"`. I want to sort it in the decreasing order with `"-NA-"` coming at top always.

I want sorted array like this:

```
[{"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
```

I tried hash.sort_by method, but got incorrect results. How to do it in Ruby?

Comment: From what you wrote, it sounds like you want to sort them as string. For example, `"5%"` would come after `"75%"` and before `"15%"` in descending order. Is this correct?

Comment: No. I want to sort them as numbers only. So, order will be : 75, then 15, 5. But NA should always come at top.

Comment: I see. Then the question was not well stated. Make it clear.

Comment: This was not a duplicate of the linked answer.  I had the same question and the other answer is insufficient due to the requirement in this question that a certain value always be sorted to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [
  {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"},
  {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"},
  {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}
]

na, rest = a.partition{|h| h["k2"] == "-NA-"}
na + rest.sort_by{|h| h["k2"].to_f}.reverse
# =>
[
  {
    "k1" => "v2",
    "k2" => "-NA-"
  },
  {
    "k1" => "v1",
    "k2" => "75.1%"
  },
  {
    "k1" => "v3",
    "k2" => "5.1%"
  }
]
```

Comment: Superb answer, sawa :) I wasn't aware of the partition method.

Comment: `"5.4&*$#%&+()".to_f` => 5.4.  Learning something new every day...

Comment: My apologies. Somehow I downvoted when I meant to upvote. Was +2 before I voted.

Comment: I corrected my mistake after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
ar = [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
ar.sort_by{|h|(k2 = h["k2"]) == "-NA-"? -Float::INFINITY : -k2.to_f}
#=>[{"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
```

Sorting of floats in descending order can be done by ordering them as their negatives.
The block will treat `"-NA-"` as the most negative number: minus Float::INFINITY; all other strings are ordered like their negative float representations would, using the ternary operator (shorthand for `if then else`).

Comment: Interesting answer. Can you explain it?

Comment: @AGS added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (commonly used) approach (with `a` from @sawa):

```
NA = "-NA-"
K2 = "k2" 
a.sort {|a,b| a[K2]==NA ? -1 : b[K2]==NA ? 1 : -a[K2].to_f <=> -b[K2].to_f }
```